# MooTools/JavaScript variable scope

Tags: javascript, loops, mootools, closures, scope

I am trying to make each number displayed clickable. "1" should `alert()` 80, "2" should produce 60, etc.

However, when the `alert(adjust)` is called, it only shows 0, not the correct numbers. However, if the commented out `alert(adjust)` is uncommented, it produces the correct number on page load, but not on clicking.

I was wondering why the code inside `addEvents` cannot access the previously defined variable `adjust`.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="mootools.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    window.addEvent('domready', function() {

            var id_numbers = [1,2,3,4,5];

            for(var i = 0; i<id_numbers.length; i++) {
                var adjust = (20 * (5 - id_numbers[i]));
                // alert(adjust);
                $('i_' + id_numbers[i]).addEvents({
                    'click': function() {
                        alert(adjust);
                    }
                });
            }

    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="i_1">1</div>
<div id="i_2">2</div>
<div id="i_3">3</div>
<div id="i_4">4</div>
<div id="i_5">5</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Comment: This is a common problem - see related questions and answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript+closures+loops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are having [a very common closure problem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3a_A_common_mistake) in that `for` loop.

Variables enclosed in a closure share the same single environment, so by the time the `click` callbacks are called, the `for` loop would have run its course, and the `adjust` variable will be left pointing to the last value it was assigned.

You can solve this with even more closures, using a function factory:

```
function makeClickHandler(adjust) {  
   return function() {  
      alert(adjust);
   };  
}

// ...

for(var i = 0; i<id_numbers.length; i++) {
   var adjust = (20 * (5 - id_numbers[i]));

   $('i_' + id_numbers[i]).addEvents({
      'click': makeClickHandler(adjust)
   });
}
```

This can be quite a tricky topic, if you are not familiar with how closures work. You may to check out the following Mozilla article for a brief introduction:

- [Mozilla Dev Center: Working with Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Closures)